# Fing-like network scanning c++

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, ipv6, arp

We're working on a network scanning feature similar to Fing. We need to discover network devices available on LAN and get their IP and MAC addresses.
Our current implementation is based on the ARP-table monitoring. So we just get the ARP table every fixed amount of time and then compare current ARP table with the previous one to find added and removed devices. This method works, but it's not perfect since there can be a big delay between the moment when the device is connected to LAN and the moment of ARP table update.

So we would like to improve current implementation. Our idea is to get a range of the IP addresses of LAN (we know the subnet mask) and then we can use SendARP() for each IP-address of the range. This will update the ARP table so we can keep using the original method. And this should work fine for IPv4 networks. But what should we do with the IPv6 networks?

Actually we have several ideas for IPv6 scanning but we are not sure, so your help, guys, will be really appreciated:

1. We can ping the address ff02::1. In theory IPv6 devices should respond when we ping this broadcast address, but it looks like it will depend on the device settings. And I'm not sure that this will force the update of the Windows ARP table.
2. Try to use Network Discovery Protocol which seems as alternative to ARP for IPv4. But I could not find any API for Windows that allows to use NDP easily.

So my questions are:

1. Will the SendArp() work fine if we'll use it as described above?
2. Is there a way to force the ARP table update in IPv6 networks?

Thanks in advance,

Vitaly

Comment: Interesting "Thanks" message, given your username.

Comment: Just a habit to put a signature at the end of message :)

Comment: IPv6 doesn't use ARP (ARP uses broadcast, and IPv6 doesn't have broadcast), so there is no ARP Cache. There is a Neighbor Cache and a Destination Cache. Network protocols really are not designed for what you want to do, but IPv6 should have a pretty complete set of neighbors in its Neighbor cache. Neighbors will send information out that will update the cache fairly often. [See RFC 4861, Neighbor Discovery for IP version 6 (IPv6), Section 5. Conceptual Model of a Host](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4861#section-5).

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for reply! You are right, ARP table is replaced with the neighbors cache for IPv6. However, according to msdn ARP cache and Neighbors cache are available via [GetIpNetTable2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Also I was testing the Neighbor cache update by turning on and off my IPv6 device and I noticed that the cache is not updating until I explicitly ping the device.

Comment: It would periodically update as devices send neighbor advertisements. Those are similar to gratuitous ARP messages, but they are more regular on IPv6.